# tensorflow on ios, building is ok , but get a error when runing, cann't create a Session , Xcode-log as follows

Tags: ios, tensorflow

2017-08-01 10:10:55.446771: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session.cc:69] Not found: No session factory registered for the given session options: {target: "" config: } Registered factories are {}.
2017-08-01 10:10:55.446878: E /Users/JamesLing/Desktop/transform/tensorflow_ios_demo/tensorflow_utils.mm:129] Could not create TensorFlow Session: Not found: No session factory registered for the given session options: {target: "" config: } Registered factories are {}.

Comment: app building success, but get a error when runing , it seams cann't create a tensorflow Session

Comment: You haven't stated what you are working with for software and hardware.  What versions of Tensorflow and Python do you have?  What version of iOS do you have? What is your device?

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the -force_load=(your tensorflow lib) flag as "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode. I have a detailed explanation for why at this point in a TF Dev Summit talk:

https://youtu.be/0r9w3V923rk?t=20m3s

Comment: This set me on the right path as well.  I added the Other Linker Flags line `-force_load /usr/local/lib/libtensorflow.so` in Xcode and the session options error went away.